# How to write self-contained YARN applications that can be ran with "hadoop -jar"?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have to run something inside a Hadoop cluster which cannot be expressed in terms of Map/Reduce. I thought of writing a YARN application for it. I discovered [Spring Yarn](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic/) for spring-boot and followed the Getting Started (see link). This works so far, but there are some flaws:

- In the tutorial three JARs are produced (one for the client, one for the appmaster and one for the container), which have to be in a specific folder structure when submitting the app
- I have to hard-code HDFS URI and Resource manager host/ports in an application.yml or supply them as command-line parameters
- Since it is based on Spring Boot, and the application is started with `java -jar`, the JAR files created are very large with basically a whole Hadoop stack in them
- The exact names of the JAR files have to be mentioned in application.yml

What I want:

- Single JAR with the JARs for appmaster and container packaged in it
- Runnable from the command line with `hadoop jar`
- Using the configuration which is available when running with `hadoop jar` (for MR2, this is possible by launching a class extending `Configured` and implementing `Tool` with `ToolRunner.run()`, this makes a `Configuration` available in the Tool's `run` method)

The approach I think of is:

1. Write the Container and AppMaster, set the YARN and Hadoop dependencies to provided in their POMs, have them packaged with the maven-shade-plugin as I do for MR jobs
2. Write the client, add the AppMaster and Container as dependencies, package it with maven-assembly-plugin to prevent the JARs from being extracted

I tried Twill, but to no avail. I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets.newCopyOnWriteArraySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArraySet;
```

because my Hadoop installation uses Guava 11 and Twill needs 13. Even though Guava 13 is shaded into the Jar, it is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I found something I call a "workaround" which works sufficiently enough for my use case:

- I build my application with Spring YARN, resulting in separate JARs for Client, Container and AppMaster
- I add them as modules to a Master POM which controls the version number (whenever I change anything in one of the former three projects, I increment the Master POM's version)
- This Master POM is a module itself, with my big whole-project-wide Parent POM
- the Master POM's parent is not the big project-wide POM, but `spring-boot-starter-parent`

When being built by Jenkins this creates the mentioned three JARs, I currently manually pack them into a folder with a start script beside them. This is just a temporary solution, as this application contains a long-running task which is later to be started by the user from a web application (also based on Spring). I still have to figure out how to submit the application from there.

My idea is the following, this is similar to how I currently do it for MR jobs:

- Add the JARs as dependencies to the web application's pom.xml
- Include a basic `application.yml` with no YARN and JAR information in the three JARs
- Use the same technique as `Job.setJarByClass()` uses to locate the AppMaster and Container JARs
- Call the client's main class with `SpringApplication.run()` passing in connection properties and the resolved locations of JAR files via the command line (`args` variable)

If anyone could give me a hint if this were a feasible situation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I dug around this some more, and found out that it is not easy to package and spawn Spring Boot apps from inside other Spring Boot apps. For my use case, calling Spring YARN applications from a Spring Boot application not using YARN, the following approach works:

1. Create the Spring YARN application in "single file mode" like in [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic-single/)
2. Package the resulting JAR into the application from where you want to deploy it

   - e.g. when using Maven, you can add it as a dependency
3. Make sure the **deploying** application excludes the `YarnClientAutoConfiguration` like so: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = YarnClientAutoConfiguration.class)`
4. Make sure the packaging plugin packages the JARs as whole archives, like the `maven-assembly-plugin` or `spring-boot-maven-plugin` does (NOT the `maven-shade-plugin`)
5. Unpack the big JAR of your deploying application to a temporary directory
6. Use a `ProcessBuilder` to run `java -jar` on the Spring-YARN application to run, passing the correct configuration options at the command line

This is all kind of hacky, Hadoop definitely needs something which is similar to the `Job` for MR jobs which just runs things on YARN.